# Smart-Table row selection issue

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I'm using the `smart-table` without `$scope` object, it looks fine, but the selection and callbacks works weird (selection happens only half the time) or do not work at all.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0PpiRlC5oDKVsdPes0IT?p=preview), I found an example, as you can see, the row selection works fine.

But if we change syntax to use 'controller As' style, then, [it does not work](http://plnkr.co/edit/uc58YM0VuyPeW3oTx1cw?p=preview)

For now, I will modify my code to use the `$scope`. But, being a beginner in AngularJS, I would be glad if someone told me why this happens and is there any way to fix that, thank you beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. your `ng-options` should be like this

   ```
   <select ng-model="events" 
       ng-options="event as event.label for event in vm.events"></select>
   ```

the `event as event.label for event in vm.events` means you're pointing to `event.label` as the `event` model for each `event` in `vm.events`

[ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

2. then add data in the controller

here is your [updated plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/eQtEwxFt8KR0y0Xu3ha0?p=preview)

**Edit 1**

1. to select the entire row you can bind `ng-click` to the `<tr>`, and pass it the current `row`, like so

   ```
   <tr ng-click="vm.selectRow(row)" ... >
   ```
2. to highlight the row, you can use `ng-class` like so

   ```
   <tr ... ng-class="{"highlight": row.selected===true}">
   ```

   and handle the selection logic in the controller. there are a lot of ways to implement this.

[forked the last plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/eQtEwxFt8KR0y0Xu3ha0?p=preview)

Comment: But it still doesn't select the rows, I didn't have problem with <select> element, though your explanation was interesting and useful, the main thing is how to select full row and get its data when clicking on it

Comment: something like this `<tr ng-click="vm.onSelectRow(row)" ...` with whatever is selected by the `select`'s ngModel?

Comment: yeah, this solves the "click" issue, but the selection is still under question, how to make it change css classes every time when I click, without hardcoding, but anyway, I can hard code it))

Comment: use `ng-class`. you can toggle css classes based on scope/vm values, i'll update the answer